# What does the "which" of "A and B which..." refer to?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, ambiguity

> A and B which...

Does what follow "which" refer to:

1. strictly B alone?
2. both A and B?

Comment: Please give real language examples.  It makes a difference what "A" and "B" are, and whether there is comma intonation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A and B, which ...

The antecedent of "which" in this case is ambiguous. But there are standard ways to make it clear, such as:

> A and B, which is ...

The antecedent is B.

> A and B, which are ...

The antecedent is A and B.